# 3D transform CSS3 cause text and images to be blurred

Tags: html, css, webkit

Text and images are blurred when 3d transform is applied?

Comment: I see some antialiasing, but no blur. It wouldn't be surprising if the 3D context's pixels didn't quite line up to the monitor, or the render (anti)aliased or interpolated a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are zooming them to be closer to the user along the z-axis. Make sure anything readable stays at z=0, by moving your whole cube back through z by half the width of the cube using a transform.

In your case, modify your #cube rules:

```
#wrapper.red #cube {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-210px) rotateY(90deg);
}
```

like that. To compensate, you'll need to make the cube wider, and make the text bigger than size 11 for it to work nicely.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rich Bradshaw. Yes you're right. I noticed that everything is zoomed.
Problem with blurry text and images fixed. Now I have zooming animation on load but that will be fixed